# unset session on direct access to a function in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, function

I have 2 functions in my controller that I'm sending a session using the first one to the second function. What I am talking about is:

```
public function search()
{

    $search_term = $this->input->post('search_term');
    $this->session->set_userdata('search_term', $search_term);

    redirect('search_result/');

}
```

and the second function:

```
function search_result()
{

    $search_term = $this->session->userdata('search_term');
    $data['search_term'] = $search_term;
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

}
```

Everything is fine but, the problem is that, I want to prevent direct access to `search_result()` function. I mean, I want to unset `search_term` session when the user calls `search_result()` directly. What should I do?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use flashdata: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages

And this is the code that do what are you looking for:

```
public function search()
{

    $search_term = $this->input->post('search_term');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('search_term', $search_term);

    redirect('search_result/');
}

function search_result()
{
    $search_term = $this->session->flashdata('search_term') ? $this->session->flashdata('search_term') : '';
    $data['search_term'] = $search_term;
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do it. Here are some

append a get parameter if it exists then search else redirect back

```
public function search()
{
    $search_term = $this->input->post('search_term');
    $this->session->set_userdata('search_term', $search_term);
    redirect('search_result?status=1');
}
public function search_result()
{
    $status =   $this->input->get('status');
    if(status == 1){
        $search_term = $this->session->userdata('search_term');
        $data['search_term'] = $search_term;
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
    }else{
        $this->session->unset_userdata('search_term');
        redirect('search');
    }
}
```

Protect you seach_result function and dont let user direct call it.
Using _ will do it for you.
[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private) is the link you can read.

```
public function search()
{
    $search_term = $this->input->post('search_term');
    $this->session->set_userdata('search_term', $search_term);
    $this->_search_result($search_term);
}
function _search_result($keyword)
{
    if(strlen($keyword)>0){
        $data['search_term'] = $keyword;
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
    }else{
        redirect('search');
    }
}
```

Comment: about the first part, I have set `enable_query_strings` to false. so I can't have something in url like that. about the second method you've told, in this case the user cannot even access to the function!!!

Comment: well you can use segment parameter instead of get in the first part like this `http://localhost/myapp/index.php/controllername/search/1` and get it like this `$status = $this->uri->segment(3);`. For the second part search_result will only be accessed through search function

Answer (score 0):

in the search function

```
redirect('search_result/'.$this->session->userdata('search_term'));
```

in the search_result function

```
function search_result()
{
    if($this->uri->segment(3))
    {
        $search_term = $this->session->userdata('search_term');
        $data['search_term'] = $search_term;
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('search_result/','refresh');
    }
}
```

hope it will help you.please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: You know what?! When I use `search()` function, it sets userdata and sends it to the `search_result()` . I use pagination class, so I can't  unset userdata at the end of `search_result()` and because of that whenever I access `search_result()` it uses the previous `userdata('search_term)` until the session expires itself !!!

Comment: ok then do not unset the session value. But make sure when you move to other function then unset the value.

Comment: I mean the code you mentioned above is not correct! because after a search for a keyword, until the session expires, whenever I try to access `search_result()` the `userdata(search_term)` wont return false!

Comment: ok then please see my updated answer and let me know the status.